Sum Topology as Finest Topology Such that Insertion is Continuous
Given a family of sets $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$, let $\psi_j: X_j \to \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ be the insertion function from $X_j$ to the disjoint union.
In wikipedia, the definition of topological sum is given as follows.
The disjoint union topology (or sum topology) on $X$ is defined as the finest topology on $X: = \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ for which all the canonical injections $\psi_j$ are continuous.
After that it states:
Explicitly, the sum topology can be described as follows. A subset $U$ of $X$ is open in $X$ if and only if its preimage $\psi_i^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i\in I$.
While I do think the second description is pretty intuitive, I can't make a proper argument that these two definitions are indeed equivalent.
So far, the main problem that lingers my mind is that I can't make use the finest property that the topology has.

Let $\tau_1$ be the finest (biggest) topology on $X$ for which all the canonical injections are continuous, and let
$$
\tau_2 = \{U \subseteq X : \text{for each $i \in I$, $\psi_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X_i$}\}.
$$
Note that if $U \in \tau_1$ and $i \in I$, $\psi_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X_i$ since $\psi_i \colon X_i \to X$ is $\tau_1$-continuous.
Hence, $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$.
On the other hand, for each $i \in I$, $\psi_i \colon X_i \to X$ is $\tau_2$-continuous by definition of $\tau_2$.
Hence, as $\tau_1$ is the finest topology on $X$ for which all the canonical injections are continuous, $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$.
